# Upload files with Volley custom body post request

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

I need to send 2 files to a server using volley library in Android.
There is an example of how it works well in Postman:
[image: example]
I need to reproduce this exactly POST call in android.
Please take a look of my code for now (which is not working):

```
JsonObjectRequest sr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Log.i("Response", response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Urine", "test");

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Authorization", "token");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            int size = (int) file.length();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
            try {
                BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                buf.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bytes;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            byte[] data = response.data;
            String message = new String(data);
            Log.i("parseNetworkResponse", String.valueOf(message));

            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
```

How can I implement this using Volley library? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrofit 2 in my opinion has been a much better and easier library to work with for file uploading.

Here is a nice and easy tut to work through. It should assist you.

[Retrofit 2 - Multifile Uploading](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-multiple-files-to-server-using-retrofit-2-in-android/)

Comment: Finally I used a retrofit library like your suggestion, while I was unable to reproduce my call using volley. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad you came right. Only a pleasure. :)